# Joining the properties of an array of objects the powershell way

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have an array of objects.

I would like to join the properties of these objects and normally I would simply do this:

```
$Objs.prop1 -join(',')
$Objs.prop2 -join(',')
$Objs.prop3 -join(',')
```

But for this case I want to do some manipulation of the properties before I join them which means I have to (hoping there is a more powershelly way) do this:

```
$ArrObj = @()
foreach ($obj in $objs) {
    $calcProp1 = [math]::Round($obj.prop1 / 1MB)
    $calcProp2 = [math]::Round($obj.prop2 / 1MB)
    $calcProp3 = [math]::Round($obj.prop3 / 1MB)
    $ArrObj += [string]$clacProp1+','+$clacProp2+','+$clacProp3}
}
```

Is there a nifty PS shortcut for doing something like this?

Comment: are the `prop1`, `prop2` and `prop3` all arrays?

Comment: Just from looking at this, it seems that example (1) would create separate comma-separated arrays _per property_ in $Objs and example (2) creates a comma-separated array _per item_ in $Objs. In other words one joins up columns of data from $Objs and one a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two code snippets do different things. Assuming that you don't want want to join the same property across all objects as in your first example, but rather join properties per object as in your second example this should do what you want:

```
$objs | ForEach-Object {
  ($_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    [math]::Round($_.Value / 1MB)
  }) -join ','
}
```

If you want just selected properties you can filter them by name:

```
$propertyNames = 'prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3'

$objs | ForEach-Object {
  ($_.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object {
    $propertyNames -contains $_.Name
  } | ForEach-Object {
    [math]::Round($_.Value / 1MB)
  }) -join ','
}
```

or use a custom function for manipulating the values before joining them:

```
function Convert-PropertyValue {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [Management.Automation.PSPropertyInfo]$Property
  )

  Process {
    switch ($Property.Name) {
      'prop1' { [math]::Round($Property.Value / 1MB) }
      'prop2' { $Property.Value + 42 }
      'prop3' { 'Value: {0:d3}' -f $Property.Value }
      default { $Property.Value }
    }
  }
}

$objs | ForEach-Object {
  ($_.PSObject.Properties | Convert-PropertyValue) -join ','
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, one pretty direct way to get an object formatted with commas between properties is to use the `ConvertTo-Csv` cmdlet, available from PSv3:

```
$Objs | Select prop1,prop2,prop3 | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Next, if you want to convert properties, you could use `Select-Object` with expressions:

```
$Objs | Select-Object -Property `
  @{Label="Calc1";Value={[math]::Round($_.prop1 / 1MB)}} `
  @{Label="Calc2";Value={[math]::Round($_.prop2 / 1MB)}} `
  @{Label="Calc3";Value={[math]::Round($_.prop3 / 1MB)}} `
  | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

A different tack could be to extend your original object using the `Add-Member` cmdlet. You can add new calculated properties:

```
$Objs | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "Calc1" -Value {[math]::Round($_.prop1 / 1MB)}}
$Objs | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "Calc2" -Value {[math]::Round($_.prop2 / 1MB)}}
$Objs | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name "Calc3" -Value {[math]::Round($_.prop3 / 1MB)}}
```

This will give you three additional properties on $Objs called Calc1|2|3, which you can then convert to CSV format:

```
$Objs | Select Calc1,Calc2,Calc3 | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I note that the OP is tagged with [powershell-v2.0] as well as [powershell-v3.0] so it may be that `ConverTo-Csv` is tantalizingly out of reach. :-( Hope this is interesting/useful in any case.

Comment: `ConvertTo-Csv` is available in both v2 and v3. In fact, it's what you'd use if you wanted to append to a CSV in v2 (`ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File -Append`), because `Export-Csv` didn't have an `-Append` parameter prior to v3.